Code ambiguity when -X file handle for file size
echo 444 > temp.txt
perl -MData::Dumper -E "open $f, pop; print Dumper [-s $f, -s($f) +10]" temp.txt

$VAR1 = [
          6,
          undef
        ];

How to tell perl it should take the size of a file and add arbitrary number to it?

( -s $f ) + 10


Unlike a sub call and unlike most function invocations, an opening paren following -s isn't taken as the start of an argument/operand list.
This means that
-s($f) +10

is parsed identically to
-s ( $f + 10 )

In this sense, -s is closer to an operator like ! than an operator like print.
The usual way to override precedence is by using parens, so a solution is to use
( -s $f ) + 10


Your parenthesis are in the wrong spot:
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e 'open $f, pop; print Dumper [ -s $f, (-s $f) + 10 ]' test.txt
$VAR1 = [
          4,
          14
        ];


When your one-liner (or even program) isn't doing what you think it should, see what Perl thinks you wrote. You can deparse a program (I left out a long use feature line):
$ perl -MO=Deparse -MData::Dumper -E 'open $f, pop; print Dumper [-s $f, -s($f) +10]' temp.txt
use Data::Dumper;
open $f, pop @ARGV;
print Dumper([-s $f, -s $f + 10]);
-e syntax OK

You see that the parens didn't matter at all. Now the question changes to which operator has higher precedence? Does the -s or the + happen first? perlop almost has the answer. The + is very high precedence table, and the "Named Unary Operators" are lower. Even if you didn't think to look for "Named Unary Operators", you still know that there's nothing above + that might fit.
As noted by others already, the fix is disambiguating parentheses: (-s $f) + 10 to get the order you want.
Now here's a little bonus. You don't need to look up the size twice. If you want the same value, you can use the special _ handle to reuse the values from the last stat (which the file test operators use to get their values). You could have:
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'open $f, pop; print Dumper [-s $f, (-s _) +10]' temp.txt

And, you don't need a file handle to use these. The filename works too:
$ perl -MData::Dumper -E 'print Dumper [-s $ARGV[-1], (-s _) +10]' temp.txt


Further down the road I'll be using filehandle, so that's why -s on a file handle.
